# Handles not being redrawn solid?

Tags: qt, qt4

I tried writing handles for a rectangle so it can be resized. It *kind of* works:

http://programmingexamples.net/wiki/Qt/Utilities/HandleItem#HandleItem.cpp

But once the handles are dragged around a little bit, most of them turn from solid-fill to outline only. There are also strange artifacts left around where the handles used to be. Eventually, some of the handles stop working all together. Can anyone explain any of these things that I am seeing? Is this approach a reasonable one? I'm still not really sure why boundingRect() has to be implemented - it seems like the objects should just maintain their position and size as state variables?

Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is likely occurring because you are drawing the handles outside of your item's boundingRect().

`boundingRect()` needs to be implemented in a lot of cases because you are doing interesting things in the `paint()` function which can go outside of what the base-class is capable of knowing.

A good debugging tip for this kind of thing is to actually draw your boundingRect() from within your paint() function, and ensure that the visible rectangle contains your item appropriately.  For example:

```
painter->setPen( Qt::red )
painter->drawRect( boundingRect() );
```

If you see that any of your items are being drawn outside of that rectangle, then it will cause the painting artifacts as the QGraphicsScene relies on its accuracy in order to determine which portions of the scene need to be repainted.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I have the right handle working properly. The when you collapse the rectangle with the left handle, the right edge moves, which is not what I want to happen (obviously). Any clues where that is going wrong? Anyone interesting in working on this please send me your github username: github.com/daviddoria/QtHandleItem